# access jhipster application from web

Tags: ubuntu, docker, jhipster

I am not familiar with web servers, but I know jhipster ships applications without the need of one. I created a very simple microservice application composed of a gateway, a microservice, the two corresponding databases and the registry. I built it with the production profile and deployed it with docker-compose on ubuntu. Now, locally everything works great, but if I try and access the application over the web with the ip of the server where it is deployed I see nothing (site can't be reached). I tried to open port 8080 (the one on which the application serves requests) but nothing happens. Is it a problem of ip binding? Where can I configure it?

result of `sudo netstat -ntlp` with the application running:

[image: result of <code>sudo netstat -ntlp</code> with the application running]

Comment: Just to confirm, have you made sure that `ufw` is not enabled or blocking port 8080?

Comment: @JonRuddell I tried both `sudo ufw allow 8080/tcp` and `sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT`, I'm editing the question attaching the result of `sudo netstat -ntlp`